# phpunit and http content-type

Tags: rest, laravel, phpunit, dingo-api

I have an API built in Laravel (Dingo) and it works perfectly. However I have a problem with implementing phpunit to unit test my API

```
class ProductControllerTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testInsertProductCase()
    {
        $data = array(
            , "description" => "Expensive Pen"
            , "price" => 100
        );

        $server = array();                        
        $this->be($this->apiUser);
        $this->response = $this->call('POST', '/products', [], [], $server, json_encode($data));
        $this->assertTrue($this->response->isOk());
        $this->assertJson($this->response->getContent());
    }

}
```

meanwhile my API endpoint points to this controller function

```
private function store()
{

    // This always returns null
    $shortInput = Input::only("price");
    $rules = [
            "price" => ["required"]
    ];
    $validator = Validator::make($shortInput, $rules);

    // the code continues
    ...
}
```

However it always fail, because the API can't recognise the payload. Input::getContent() returns the JSON but Input::only() returns blank. Further investigation this is because Input::only() only returns value if the content type of the request payload is on JSON

So ... how do I set my phpunit code above to use content-type application/json ? I am assuming it must have something to do with `$server` but I don't know what

Edit:
There are actually 2 problems with my original thinking

1. Input::getContent() works because I fill the sixth parameter but Input::only() doesn't work because i didn't fill the third parameter. Thanks to @shaddy
2. How to set content-type in phpunit request header is still unanswered

Thanks heaps

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The third parameter of the call function must be the parameters you send to the controller as input parameters - in your case the data parameter.

> $response = $this->call($method, $uri, $parameters, $cookies, $files, $server, $content);

Changing your code like the example below should work (you do not have to json_encode the array):

```
$this->response = $this->call('POST', '/products', $data);
```

In Laravel 5.4 and above, you can verify the response of headers like the Content-Type like so ([docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/http-tests#assert-header)):

```
$this->response->assertHeader('content-type', 'application/json');
```

or for Laravel 5.3 and below ([docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.3/testing)):

```
$this->assertEquals('application/json', $response->headers->get('Content-Type'));
```

Comment: Thanks that make the phpunit test works as it should. The original question, though, how do you set the content-type in phpunit test case? Or do I need not to worry about the content-type?

Comment: @DonDjoe I have updated my answer with example how you can verify the response content type.

Comment: Thanks @shaddy, how do I set the content type of the request though? Not verify

Comment: @DonDjoe You can do it like this in your controller `return response($content, $status)->header('Content-Type', $value);`

Comment: Thanks again. However, how do I set it in the phpunit test case? Not controller

Comment: @DonDjoe In the request you can pass it as server parameter like this `$this->response = $this->call('POST', '/products', $data, [], [], ['CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json']);`